# JButton & ActionListener

Tags: java

Сейчас пишу калькулятор, вот появился небольшой вопрос:
создаю кнопки из массива строк (чтобы много места не занимали)

```
String [] buttonName = {"1","2","3","/","4","5","6","*","7","8","9","+","0","-","C","="};  
for (String string : buttonName) {  
    panel2.add(new JButton(String.valueOf(string)));  
}
```

Как, в таком случае, к каждой кнопке добавить ActionListener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, есть разные способы. Но в общем случае делается это в таком духе

```
public class Test {

    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();

    void test() {
        String[] buttonName = {"1", "2", "3", "/", "4", "5", "6", "*", "7", "8", "9", "+", "0", "-", "C", "="};
        for (String string : buttonName) {
            panel2.add(createButton(string));
        }
    }

    private JButton createButton(String string) {
        JButton btn = new JButton(string);
        btn.addActionListener(new CalcButtonActionListener(string));
        return btn;
    }

}

class CalcButtonActionListener implements ActionListener {
    private final String buttonName;

    public CalcButtonActionListener(String buttonName) {
        this.buttonName = buttonName;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // do something with digit or action
    }
}
```

Comment: ммм спасибо, сейчас буду пробовать) потом отпишусь ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
  final List < String > buttons = new LinkedList < String > ();
  buttons.add ( "this" );
  buttons.add ( "is" );
  buttons.add ( "a" );
  buttons.add ( "test" );

  final JFrame frame = new JFrame ();
  for ( final String name : buttons )
  {
     final AbstractAction a = new AbstractAction ( name )
     {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed ( final ActionEvent e )
        {
           System.out.println ( this );
        }
     };
     frame.add ( new JButton ( a ) );
  }
```

Comment: Интересный code conventions для java.

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл вот такое решение:

```
for (Component comp : panel2.getComponents()) {  
    if (comp instanceof JButton) {  
        ((JButton)comp).addActionListener(new CalcButtonListener());  
    }  
}
```